# Problem with raster calculator gdal_calc.py

Tags: gdal-calc

I have two rasters. One with the following values: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
and the other one with continuous values ranging from 0 to 10000. I would like to create a raster where only values of the second raster will be kept when the first raster has values from 4 to 6. How could I do this using gdal_calc.py?

I tried:

```
gdal_calc.py -A first_raster.tif -B second_raster.tif --outfile=Result.tif --calc="B*(3<=A>=7)" --NoDataValue=0
```

But I get a Value Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is that the correct way to introduce this condition in to the raster calculator?
I thought that follows the same logic than the raster calculator used in QGIS, where the value in the ouput we want goes together with the * simbol and the condition goes in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe gdal_calc.py doesn't cope well with combined relations such as (3<=A>=7). It might be better to split it up:

```
--calc="B*logical_and(3 <= A, A >= 7)"
```

Comment: AND is not a thing. You mean `logical_and(3 <= A, A >= 7)`